# PyPy C/API access

Tags: python, api, pypy

I've been looking through the reference docs and can't find any mention of a C API for PyPy. Does it exist? If so is it the same as the CPython C API? If PyPy was run on top of CPython would it change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyPy has [alpha-level support](http://pypy.org/compat.html) for the CPython extension API via an emulation layer called CPyExt.  Here's a [blog post introducing the support](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-cpython-extension-modules-with.html); here's [a later one discussing it](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/05/numpy-follow-up.html).  If your goal is to interface with a C library, you're probably best off just writing a Python wrapper module that uses [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to call into it.

Running PyPy on CPython wouldn't help (besides slowing things down terribly), because the API wouldn't interact with *PyPy's* object model—it would interact with that of the CPython host environment.

Comment: My aim is using it for embedding Python into a C++ application

Comment: Does the application already use the Python C API?  What's your goal in embedding?  (Here's a rant on embedding vs. extending that may or may not be appropriate for your use case: http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/rant/extendit.html)

Comment: We use it for embedding at the moment. I am aware of all of the arguments against it, but extending isn't an option in our current setup which we are forced into to integrate with other parts of the system. Spent a long time explaining this might not be the best solution but no one else agrees as it is more work